# Prime dividing $4n^2+1$ congruent to $1\pmod{4}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that for any integer $n$, any prime $p$ such that $p\mid 4n^2+1$ is congruent to $1\pmod{4}$.

I am using this as a step to prove that there are infinitely many primes that are congruent to $1\pmod{4}$, but I want to prove this using this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $p$ is a prime dividing $4n^2+1$.

Then, if we define $x=2n$:

$x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$

$\left(x^2\right)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod{p} $

$x^{p-1} \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod{p}$

$(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}\ $      by Fermat's theorem

$(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = 1$

And, so:   $\ p\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$

Answer (score 1):

We have $(2n)^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p$ and so $2n \bmod p$ has multiplicative order $4$. By Lagrange's theorem of group theory, $4$ divides the order of the multiplicative group mod $p$, which is $p-1$.

Comment: Very good answer! Amazing.